# Different templates for each model object in Django

Tags: django-models, routes, django-views

I have a Departments model:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, default='', unique=False)
```

There are 3 objects in this model: Department_1, Department_2, Department_3.
I want each model object to transition to its own html-template.
To do this, I wrote 3 view classes (for each template, respectively):

```
class Department_1_View(DetailView):
    model = Department
    template_name = 'deps/department_1_detail.html'
    context_object_name = "depp"
    slug_url_kwarg = 'dep_slug'
```

Accordingly, class Department_2_View is created for department_2_detail.html, and class Department_3_View is created for department_3_detail.html.
The routes are:

```
path('deps/<slug:dep_slug>/',views.Department_1_View.as_view(), name="dep_1"),
path('deps/<slug:dep_slug>/',views.Department_2_View.as_view(), name="dep_2"),
path('deps/<slug:dep_slug>/',views.Department_3_View.as_view(), name="dep_3"),
```

Further in the for loop, I try to do a check, but despite this, all departments go along the first (upper) route. What can I do to make each department go to its own unique template from the menu? Where can I write such a condition? My loop with conditional checking is something like this:

```
{% for d in departments %}
  {% if d.slug == 'Department_1' %}
    <a href="{% url 'dep_1' d.slug %}" {{ d.name }}</a>
  {% elif d.slug == 'Department_2' %}
    <a href="{% url 'dep_2' d.slug %}" {{ d.name }}</a>
  {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'dep_3' d.slug %}" {{ d.name }}</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[sidebar_menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMs3z.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the view.py using "get_template_names" method like this:

```
class DepartmentView(DetailView):
    model = Department
    context_object_name = "depp"
    slug_url_kwarg = 'dep_slug'
    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.object.slug == 'Department_1':
            return ['deps/department_1_detail.html']
        elif self.object.slug == 'Department_2':
            return ['deps/department_2_detail.html']
        else:
            return ['deps/department_3_detail.html']
```

That is, instead of three views, one remained.
Of the three routes, in the end, we also leave only one route:

```
path('deps/<slug:dep_slug>/', views.DepartmentView.as_view(), name="dep")
```

And in the for loop:

```
{% for d in departments %}
  <a href="{% url 'dep' d.slug %}" {{ d.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Everything works, but the downside is that if there are a lot of objects, you will have to prescribe conditions for each object in the view.py.